# How to achieve INotifyPropertyChanged functionality for the values in a bool[]?

Tags: wpf, binding, inotifypropertychanged

I have a bool array of size 4 and I want to bind each cell to a different control.
This bool array represents 4 statuses (false = failure, true = success).
This bool array is a propery with a class:

```
class foo : INotifyPropertyChanged {
...
private bool[] _Statuses;
public bool[] Statuses
{
    get {return Statuses;}
    set {
            Statuses = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Statuses");
        }
}
```

In XAML there are 4 controls, each one bound to one cell of the array:

```
... Text="{Binding Path=Statuses[0]}" ...
... Text="{Binding Path=Statuses[1]}" ...
... Text="{Binding Path=Statuses[2]}" ...
... Text="{Binding Path=Statuses[3]}" ...
```

The problem is that the notify event is raised only when I change the array itself and isn't raised when I change one value within the array, i.e, next code line raises the event:

```
Statuses = new bool[4];
```

but next line does not raises the event:

```
Statuses [0] = true;
```

How can I raise the event each time one cell is changed?

Answer (score 9):

You need to expose your statuses as an indexer, then raise a property change event that indicates that the indexer has changed.

```
private bool[] _Statuses;

public bool this[int index]
{
    get { return _Statuses[index]; }
    set
    {
        _Statuses[index] = value;

        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Binding.IndexerName));
    }
}
```

See this blog post:

http://10rem.net/blog/2010/03/08/wpf---silverlight-quick-tip-inotifypropertychanged-for-indexer

Comment: You missed a parenthesis when you raise the property changed event.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't raise the event becuase `Array` itself doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. You can either use a different container than the primitive array (anything that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` liked `ObservableCollection<T>` should do) OR you have to call `RaisePropertyChanged("Statuses")` each time you update the Statuses array OR, as metioned in another answer, use one class that implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` that contains 4 properties.

Comment: Yes, using ObservableCollection will be the simplest way to go.

Comment: `ObservableCollection<T>` doesn't notify when a value of any item inside it is changed.

Comment: @decyclone: it notifies if the nth item of the collection is moved,replaced, etc, which is what the OP's code does. You are correct in that this won't handle the case in which T has properties and doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged, but I considered that outside the scope of the question.

Comment: you are right. I did not realize this will be a collection of value types (Boolean) and not a class.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it while using an `Array`. Changing a value at any index on an `Array` does not raise change notification required by the `UI`.

Can you use a class with four properties that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface instead?